# Android file copy

Tags: android, file-io, copy

I am finding that reading one line at a time from a text file on the SD card is rather slow. I imagine that it might be quicker if the file is in internal memory, so I want to copy files from the SD card to internal storage.

The file copy examples I can find on the web seem to involve copying one byte at a time from an InputStream to an OutputStream or from a FileReader to a FileWriter. Is this really the quickest and most efficient method?

Comment: FWIW, on some devices the SD card is faster than internal Flash.  You may want to try a couple of I/O benchmarks.

Comment: Thanks. (In fact, I've realised that I/O speed was not the big issue for me ... it turned out that the method I was using to display HTML-format text was very inefficient and was causing the major delay. This is discussed on another thread.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are pulling the file in for use in your application what I suggest you do is read in the data then stuff the in memory data you have collected into some kind of reader (BufferedReader perhaps) so that you can then read the lines from there.

Here is an example of what I typically do:

```
// Assumption: I already have the file object I want to read
// Note: I'm not doing any error handling.
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead = 0;
while( (bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) > 0){
    baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader( new String(baos.toByteArray()) );
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( stringReader );
for(String line : bufferedReader.readLine()){
    // TODO: Handle each line appropriately or something
    Log.d("Reading Data Example", line);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks like just what I need (assuming I can have a ByteArray large enough to hold up to 2 megabytes).

Comment: OK. I've followed your example code and it seems to work well. However, the result is that reading via the BAOS and StringReader seems to be slightly slower than simply using `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));`. This has caused me to use LogCat to look more carefully at the timings and I see that the process of reading text in from the file is quite quick, even reading from the SD card. I now see that I asked the wrong question. ...

Comment: ... the greater problem is the time taken to display the extracted text. My code reads selected lines from the input file into a StringBuilder object sb, then displays that in a TextView using `tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()));` For 50 "lines" (or paragraphs) averaging about 1KB per line the 3 lines of code: `  setContentView(R.layout.displaytext);
  TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display_text);
  tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(text.toString()));
` take 5 seconds or more to process. Do you have any suggestions as to how to speed up this display? Should ask this as a new question?

Comment: I think it might be appropriate as another question. To make a quick suggestion, perhaps doing some AsyncTasks to offload the work from the UI thread then just updating the UI when data comes in could help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I'm afraid multiple-threading is too complicated for me. Besides, there are no other tasks for the app to get on with while waiting for the text to be displayed.

Comment: AsyncTasks make Threading Easy!  A good tutorial is up on the android developer blog.  [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)

Comment: Thanks. I've looked at the Painless Threading link. AsyncTasks do look quite easy to implement, as you say. However, even the simple example introduces unfamiliar syntax: what do the angle-brackets in `extends AsyncTask<string, void,="" bitmap="">` mean? Are these the "generics" referred to in `You can specify the type, using generics, of the parameters, the progress values and the final value of the task`? And what does the ellipsis ("...") in `doInBackground(String... urls)` mean? I wonder if there is an even more basic guide anywhere!?

Comment: @prepbgg `AsyncTasks` *sound* easy but they gloss over the difficulty in a responsible implementation--handling cases when the parent `Activity` dies, or the screen rotates, etc.  These are difficult to test and even more difficult to get right.  When you get it wrong, expect run-time exceptions.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. Luckily, I seem to be getting by without having to attempt AsyncTasks. :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the truisims of CS that only becomes more true with time as CPUs get faster is: **I/O is slow**.

If you want speed, generally your best bet is to **do as few I/O's as possible**. Ideally, find out how big that file is, allocate that much memory, and then **read the entire thing in one big I/O**. Then you can just access the data from program memory. If you might not have enough RAM for every concievable file size then you might have to do a bit more work, but this is what you should strive for.

Comment: Thanks for your very prompt answer. My maximum text file size is probably less than 2 megabytes and the "lines" of text can be anything up to a few kilobytes. I have been using a BufferedReader to read from the SD card a line at a time. Can you recommend the most appropriate data structure to hold the file and the methods I should use to read in in bulk from SD and then to read from program memory one line at a time, please?

Comment: If your goal is to process HTML data, perhaps you should look into a streaming parser. I believe the apache libraries and/or xerces can achieve this. Also, I found this page in the android dev docs. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html