# Android adb sideload command

Tags: android, adb, rom

I am reading a tutorial on the sideload command at [link](http://android-revolution-hd.blogspot.com/2013/12/ow-to-use-adb-sideload.html).

It contains the steps of rebooting into recovery mode and using adb sideload [file].zip.

My question is that what does sideload actually do with that zip file ? In the past I have compiled AOSP and flashed a device using

- adb reboot-bootloader
- adb fastboot flashall -w

Is sideload trying to achieve something similar to the above ?

**Edit:**

I think my confusion relating to sideload stems from my lack of understanding of how Android's memory is structured. I found two links.

First is a link that explains Android partitions : [partitions](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/android-partitions-explained-boot-system-recovery-data-cache-misc/)

Second is a SO answer, that explains Android's memory: [memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634774/android-memory-types-ram-v-internal-memory/4634858#4634858)

Now my understanding so far is this :

Android has RAM and ROM. ROM is divided into several partitions, namely, /system, /data, /boot, /recovery, /cache, /misc and /sdcard.

Now the link relating to sideload states that this command installs a zip file.

What I don't understand still is that, is this zip file, going to replace the entire ROM in Android ? Namely, will it have to have the right partitions as in the list above ?

This also makes me confused about a similar command 'fastboot flashall'. I know when I run it, the terminal goes by saying its writing to several of the partitions. So my questions boil down to these :

1) Is sideload replacing entire ROM ?

2) Is the related command 'fastboot flashall' also replacing entire ROM ?

3) Are there ways to replace select partitions ?

Thanks.

Comment: Sideload means instead of installing an Android app via Google Play you will be installing an app via "unofficial" channel like ADB.

Comment: @ChuongPham - that's what it previously meant to everybody else, but it's clearly not what it means in this context for ADB.  After all, to "sideload" an *app* the command you use is "adb install"  This appears to involve applying system updates - which could of course include apps, but would not be limited to that.

Comment: I think http://android.stackexchange.com would be the best people to ask this question of.

Comment: If you're absolutely stuck like I was, try a different host device or new installation instead of giving up! → https://android.stackexchange.com/a/234460/340401

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes and no. `adb reboot-bootloader` is used to get yoi into fastboot mode ard sideload is used to apply updates to a system which can be (and is oftenly) used to **overwrite** a stock OS. I used sideload for exactly that, my fairphone also delivers [a small utility to factory reset every partioin of it using `adb` and `sideload`](https://support.fairphone.com/hc/en-us/articles/360048148532) (this is the Windows version from [scroll down here](https://support.fairphone.com/hc/en-us/articles/360048050332)). Consider [chris stratton's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/429063/chris-stratton) comment. You can look into `adb backup` and `adb restore` to only deal with user data and apps. [Click me tenderly](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/66617/340401), [click me hard](https://stackpointer.io/mobile/android-adb-backup-extract-restore-repack/372/). Pay attention as to [apps can opt out of this](https://forum.f-droid.org/t/fennec-is-it-necessary-to-opt-out-of-the-adb-backups/12112/5) - explanation in [this brilliant answer by Izzy](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/182384/340401).
2. Depends but more or less yes. `fastboot flashall` is typically used to flash the recovery partition only to boot from there and continue with sideload (*see 1.*).
3. There definitely are, but I'm not able to do it on my own. The [referred utility](https://support.fairphone.com/hc/en-us/articles/360048148532) does exactly that. It should be possible to figure out the exact commands or find a similar utility for your manufacturer. I misused mine to flash everything I needed for me. To do so, i just replaced the respcetive `.img` files such as `boot.img` [image: Inside the folder of this tool: https://support.fairphone.com/hc/en-us/articles/360048148532]