# What is the difference between cache data in-memory and caching to disk in android?

Tags: java, android, memory, kotlin

What is the difference between cache data **in-memory** and **caching to disk** in android?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/4634774/4465208 ?

Answer (score 1):

**Use a Memory Cache**

A memory cache offers fast access to data/bitmaps at the cost of taking up valuable application memory.

disadvandages --->its memory limits and crash

**Use a Disk Cache**

If you use Memory Cache,application could be interrupted by another task like a phone call, and while in the background it might be killed and the memory cache destroyed. Once the user resumes, your application has to process each image again.

A disk cache can be used in these cases to persist processed bitmaps and help decrease loading times where images are no longer available in a memory cache.

The memory cache is checked in the UI thread, the disk cache is checked in the background thread

for more detail refer  [Memory and Disk cache](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap)