# How to create a independent and full copy of a File object?

Tags: android, file, file-io, android-file

Official facebook App has a bug, when you try to share an image with share intent, the image gets deleted from the sdcard. This is the way you have to pass the image to facebook app using the uri of the image:

```
File myFile= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "car.jpg");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(myFile);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

Then,  suppose that if i create a copy from the original `myFile` object, and i pass the uri of the copy to facebook app, then, my original image will not be deleted.

I tried with this code, but it doesn't work, the original image file is still getting deleted:

```
    File myFile= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "car.jpg");
    File auxFile=myFile.getAbsoluteFile();      
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(auxFile);
```

Can someone tell me how to do a exact copy of a file that doesn't redirect to the original File?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check: [Android file copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615693/android-file-copy)

The file is copied byte by byte so no reference to the old file is maintained.

Comment: You didn't understand my question, your link didn't answer to my question

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the response. If you do a byte copy of the file no reference should be maintained. Check the first answer to the question in the link. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but probably i didn't explain the question perfectly. I dont need a outputstream, and i dont have a input stream. I have a File object, and i need to create a independent copy of the object, another File object with the same content with no reference maintained.

Comment: You can create the streams from input files 
`InputStream in = new FileInputStream(myFile);
var myFile2 = new File(<PATH>);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myFile2);`

Comment: Just a comment on the code you tried in your question, there you have 2 File objects related to the same physical file on disk. That's why when deleted it is deleted in both.

Answer (score 1):

Here, this should be able to create a copy of your file:

```
private void CopyFile() {

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
          in = new FileInputStream(<file path>);
          out = new FileOutputStream(<output path>);
          copyFile(in, out);
          in.close();
          in = null;
          out.flush();
          out.close();
          out = null;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }       
}
private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
      out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but you are not answering to my question. Probably i didn't explain the question perfectly. I dont need a outputstream, and i dont have a input stream. I have a File object, and i need to create a independent copy of the object, another File object with the same content.

Comment: This should create an exact duplicate of your file. After it has been created, you can specify another File object and assign the new file to it. You simply need to provide your file path to this code, and it will copy the file for you to the sdcard with 2 appended to the name.