# Image is saved in application folder with 0 byte size in Kotlin?

Tags: android, image, kotlin

> I am using the third party library to open the Gallery and camera. I
>   have done that part. Now, when i select multiple image or single
>   image,got the array of URI from the third party lib. Now, i created the file
>   in app package folder and able to create it. But when i check under
>   app folder, the size of an image is 0 byte. I am saving the path also
>   on local db and later will upload it on server using multipart. Below
>   is my code.

To open the Gallery and camera

```
private fun openPicker() {
    PhotoPickerFragment.newInstance(
        multiple = true,
        allowCamera = true,
        maxSelection = 5,
        theme = R.style.ChiliPhotoPicker_Light
    ).show(childFragmentManager, "picker")
}
```

got the selected image path URI and save path in to local db with createFile

```
override fun onImagesPicked(photos: ArrayList<Uri>) {

        Log.e("TAG", "pic" + photos.joinToString(separator = "\n") { it.toString() })

        fileList = ArrayList<File>()

        try {
            photos.forEachIndexed { index, e ->
                println("$e at ${photos[index].path}")
                val destinationFile: File = createImageFile()
                fileList.add(destinationFile)

                fileList.also {

                    // Get the file-name from the image-path
                    val destinationFilePath = it[index].absolutePath
                    val fileName =
                        destinationFilePath.substring(destinationFilePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)

                    val attachment = AttachSiteImage()
                    attachment.apply {
                        callLoggingId = callLoggingIdForAttachment
                        attachmentFileName = fileName
                        attachmentPath = destinationFilePath

                    }
                    attachImageviewModel?.addAttachFromApi(attachment)
                }
            }
            Log.e("TAG", "Path->" + fileList.size)

        } catch (ex: FileAlreadyExistsException) {
            //  sourceFile.delete()
            cl_attachments_main_container.showSnackBar(
                if (!ex.localizedMessage.isNullOrEmpty())
                    ex.localizedMessage
                else
                    ex.stackTrace.toString(),
                Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
            )
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            //   sourceFile.delete()
            cl_attachments_main_container.showSnackBar(
                if (!ex.localizedMessage.isNullOrEmpty())
                    ex.localizedMessage
                else
                    ex.stackTrace.toString(),
                Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
            )
        }
    }
```

Create the file where photos will be stored

```
 @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun createImageFile(): File {
        // Create an image file name
        val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
        val storageDir: File? = requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        return File.createTempFile(
            "${callLoggingIdForAttachment}_${timeStamp}_", /* prefix */
            ".jpg", /* suffix */
            storageDir /* directory */
        )
    }
```

Here is the Library URL: https://github.com/ChiliLabs/ChiliPhotoPicker

Comment: Well, your code creates an empty file with `createTempFile` and doesn't seem to write anything to it. If `addAttachFromApi` is supposed to do that, show it!

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Yes. I can see the files under package->files with 0bytes. attachImageviewModel?.addAttachFromApi(attachment) this line add the image from device to local db. I think i have to copy the files when image  capture or image selected in to package->files folder

Answer (score 1):

Your `createImageFile()` function creates an empty file by returning a result of [`createTempFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)), not an image file. You don't write anything to that empty file and use it as the attachment. And in

```
// Get the file-name from the image-path
val destinationFilePath = it[index].absolutePath
```

you don't use the image path as the comment says; you use the path of the empty file you just created.

The image file is given to you as `Uri`, `e` in

```
photos.forEachIndexed { index, e ->
```

but you ignore it except to log

```
println("$e at ${photos[index].path}")
```

So [convert `Uri` to `File`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975197/convert-file-uri-to-file-in-android/8370299)

```
val destinationFile = File(e.path)
```

and work with that. Or [copy it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133579/android-save-a-file-from-an-existing-uri) to the file created by `createImageFile` if that's what you want (answers there are for Java but IDEA/Android Studio can convert them to Kotlin for you).