# How to create an internal file or directory for saving the uri of the images picked from gallery?

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite

Hi Guys I created an app that save URI of images that picked from gallery by the user in the SQLite database, however when I change the location of the images or I delete them my app crushes when try to read them by their URIs from gallery. So I searched in google and I found most people recommend to create an internal file or directory of the app for saving those images but I have no idea how can I create an internal file/directory for my app.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#internal-access-files

Comment: @JakeLee Okay i will check the doc, thank u for the link :)

Comment: Saving urls  in a file instead of a database makes no difference is the file becomes deleted. You should simply catch the exception that lets you app crash now.

Comment: I think he might be saying he wants to create a dir and copy the images there so he retains them even if the user deleted them?

Comment: @spartygw hah yeah exactly, do you have any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: @blackapps I'm trying to do  like #spartygw said

Comment: I think converting URI to Bitmap will be a solution to saving images in an internal directory?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133579/android-save-a-file-from-an-existing-uri

Comment: @spartygw Thank, but it seems in this case they used external storage not internal

Comment: Yeah, just create a folder in your sandbox with `getFilesDir`

Comment: @spartygw as I know it's better to store them in internal storage bcz it's secure and can hold more data than external

Comment: `think converting URI to Bitmap will be a solution to saving images in an internal directory?` @Mark Lee. No. Just copy the file. No messing around with bitmaps. Makes no sense. If you would copy a pdf file you would not use a bitmap either.

Comment: @blackapps yeah u're right even though in my case  i'm sure i'm not gonna use pdf or videos i think copying them will be the best option