# How to Move or Copy/Paste Files on Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I've searched through the internet for how to move or copy'n'paste files on an Android device programmatically, but i found nothing up to now. what i wish to do is, that my application copies or moves a SQLite Database from the internal sdcard to the app folder in /data/data/example. i would be pleased if someone could explain my how to do that or give me a link to somewhere it gets explained.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search on Stackoverflow turns out two questions with helpful answers:

[How to make a copy of a file in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292954/how-to-make-a-copy-of-a-file-in-android)

[Android file copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615693/android-file-copy)

Basically, they suggest to read the contents of one file and write those to another file. You can do the same with monodroid.

Comment: thanks for your help, i have to learn to use more the forums and less google.

Comment: now i have figured out, that Mono for android has some methods like File.Copy(source,destination) or Move(src,dst). but atm i get the error that the two "places" would not be on the same device... well, what i use to get my paths are `Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString() + "Filename.example"` as source(the internal SD-Card), and `Android.OS.Environment.DataDirectory.ToString() + "/data/Example.Example/files"` as destination.